# MySQL query analyser

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Im working on Ruby on Rails and MySQL,

I wanna know if there is some open source tool to analyze the performance of SQL queries so that I can write queries accordingly and also change by table structures accordingly.

Im new to this so please don't mind stupid questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Free tools: [Percona Software for MySQL](http://www.percona.com/software/), [mysqlsla](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlsla), [MaatKit](http://www.maatkit.org/)

Not free but has a trial:  [MySQL query analyser](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html)

Comment: love that it has the same title as the OP's title.